# Windows Server Backup (2012) to Both Local Volume and Remote Folder

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-backup

As I understand it, you can use Windows Server Backup on Windows Server 2012 R2 to schedule a backup to either a local volume daily (and it stores multiple daily backups) or you can backup to shared folder (and it stores one day that is overwritten each time).

How can I do both?  I want to have the daily backups on the local volume in case I need to restore something from the past few weeks, but I want one backup of everything on a removable hard drive in case of fire (and I just grab the drive before exiting the building).

Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted:  If you schedule a backup to a remote folder, it will overwrite the previous backup each time it runs.  If you schedule a backup to a local disk, it manages the backups using VSS in a file-system-level-manipulation-unfriendly way.

What I would recommend:

1. Schedule a regular backup via the GUI to an attached disk and let Windows Server Backup/VSS manage that disk.
2. Share a second backup disk on a different server.
3. Use the command line to schedule a [(copy)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742083.aspx) backup to a remote share via task scheduler (`Wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:\\YourSecondServer\SecondDiskShare -vssCopy`) via Task Scheduler.

Comment: Thank you.  That'll be great.  However, will the copy backup overwrite the previous backup automatically or will I have to manage versions?  (I'm looking for an overwriting solution.)

Comment: It overwrites automatically.